# is it possible to provide custom name for internal delegated properties in kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

I have the following code snippet and I want to access `scriptDsl` property from `Java` internally from the same code base. I do not want to expose `scriptDsl` publically.

```
class ScriptDsl {
    internal val scriptDsl: JScriptDsl by lazy { //... }
}
```

when compiled, `scriptDsl` becomes `public final JScriptDsl getScriptDsl$esw_ocs_dsl_kt()` but I want to provide custom name here which is possible for non delegated properties using `JvmName("scriptDsl")`.
How to do it for `internal delegated properties`?

I am fine if there are any other better solutions, my requirements are"

- I want to call `scriptDsl` from java within the same module
- I am calling it using reflection so need to know the name beforehand
- `ScriptDsl` is public and I do not want property `scriptDsl` to be accessed outside module
- `scriptDsl` has to be lazy because it depends on other properties which might not be avaibale while declaration

Note: I know `internal` in kotlin is `public` in java.

From kotlin docs:

***internal*** declarations become public in Java. Members of internal classes go through name mangling, to make it harder to accidentally use them from Java and to allow overloading for members with the same signature that don't see each other according to Kotlin rules;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify your annotation target to getter like this:

```
class ScriptDsl {
    @get:JvmName("scriptDsl")
    internal val scriptDsl: JScriptDsl by lazy { //... }
}
```

and then just call it with `scriptDsl`:

```
ScriptDsl scriptDsl = new ScriptDsl();
scriptDsl.scriptDsl();
```